# Google Cloud Dataflow Pub/Sub to BigQuery template WriteSuccessfulRecords wall time

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Currently getting astronomical wall time with standard `pubsub_to_bigquery` template. Only parsing in about 10 keys. `WriteSuccessfulRecords` is showing over 11 hours!

[image]

When I break this out, I see that `StreamingWrite` is the culprit, however I can see the data immediately in `BigQuery`.

[image]

Is this just a buffering issue (i.e. keeping the buffer available/open for extended periods) or should I be concerned?

Comment: can you paste some code?

Comment: the data being parsed into the pub/sub that feeds into dataflow is simple key/value: "keyA":"valueA","keyB":"valueB","keyC":"valueC","keyD":"valueD" which is then inserted into bigquery

Comment: How long have you be running the pipeline and how many records have you published to pipeline?

Comment: @RyanMcDowell the pipeline has been running for 9 days and receives 23 records a minute consistently (IoT data coming in)

Comment: I don't want to see the data really - I want to see how the pipeline that gives you these results is exactly configured.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa - It's a Google provided template but the code in question is part of the BigQueryIO transform located at: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/StreamingWriteTables.java#L161

Answer (score 4):

In streaming mode the wall time of the step will accumulate forever since the input is unbounded. The reason you're seeing such a high wall time is because the pipeline has been running for 9 days and thus the accumulation is becoming large. Wall time is defined as:

> Approximate time spent in this step on initializing, processing data, shuffling data, and terminating, across all threads in all workers. For composite steps, the sum of time spent in the component steps.

Since the [StreamingWrite](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/StreamingWriteFn.java) transform makes API calls to the BigQuery service, this is likely to be the most expensive step of the pipeline (if no custom  transformations) because the API calls leave the worker.

In your case, the wall clock seconds per hour can be calculated as
`(((((11*60) + 16) * 60) + 31) / 9) / 24 = 187.92`. This means the step spends just over 3 mins per hour writing out the inserts within that step. The step looks expensive because the amount of time it's been running (and thus the accumulated wall-time) but it's really just working as intended.

Comment: thanks for the response Ryan. Is there a way to determine the average time for the step to process each message?

Comment: You won't be able to edit the core transforms to do this but you can do it in your own custom ParDo and transforms using the Metrics API with a Distribution metric (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.6.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/Metrics.html).


You can see some example code of this functionality in the unit tests for the Metrics API (https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/test/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/metrics/MetricsTest.java#L106)

Comment: @RyanMcDowell Where does the `/ 9` and `/ 24` come from in your calculation? is there any other documentation resource where "Wall time" is actually specified?

Comment: @Cristian -- The first portion of the equation puts the wall-time of the `StreamingWrite` step in seconds. `11 hours * 60 minutes in an hour` to get the minutes. We then add the `16 minutes` of the step to that result. Then we multiply by `60` again and add `31` to get the total time in seconds. Then, since the pipeline has been running for `9 days`, we divide by `9` and then by `24` to get the breakdown in hours. There is a help tool tip on the sidebar when running a Dataflow job which explains wall-time.

Comment: I've seen it, and it says exactly what you quoted in your answer. But it's not really easy to understand, and its definition of wall time is different to the conventional definition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elapsed_real_time Thanks for the breakdown though!

Comment: By the way... I got to this post because I was trying to understand the behavior of a pipeline I'm trying to build right now which feels slower than it should. In case you have spare time to lend me a hand: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52812292/how-to-parallelize-http-requests-within-an-apache-beam-step