# How to parallelize HTTP requests within an Apache Beam step?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have an Apache Beam pipeline running on Google Dataflow whose job is rather simple:

- It reads individual JSON objects from Pub/Sub
- Parses them
- And sends them via HTTP to some API

This API requires me to send the items in batches of 75. So I built a `DoFn` that accumulates events in a list and publish them via this API once they I get 75. This results to be too slow, so I thought instead of executing those HTTP requests in different threads using a thread pool.

The implementation of what I have right now looks like this:

```
private class WriteFn : DoFn<TheEvent, Void>() {
  @Transient var api: TheApi

  @Transient var currentBatch: MutableList<TheEvent>

  @Transient var executor: ExecutorService

  @Setup
  fun setup() {
    api = buildApi()
    executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()
  }

  @StartBundle
  fun startBundle() {
    currentBatch = mutableListOf()
  }

  @ProcessElement
  fun processElement(processContext: ProcessContext) {
    val record = processContext.element()

    currentBatch.add(record)

    if (currentBatch.size >= 75) {
      flush()
    }
  }

  private fun flush() {
    val payloadTrack = currentBatch.toList()
    executor.submit {
      api.sendToApi(payloadTrack)
    }
    currentBatch.clear()
  }

  @FinishBundle
  fun finishBundle() {
    if (currentBatch.isNotEmpty()) {
      flush()
    }
  }

  @Teardown
  fun teardown() {
    executor.shutdown()
    executor.awaitTermination(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
  }
}
```

This seems to work "fine" in the sense that data is making it to the API. But I don't know if this is the right approach and I have the sense that this is very slow.

The reason I think it's slow is that when load testing (by sending a few million events to Pub/Sub), it takes it up to 8 times more time for the pipeline to forward those messages to the API (which has response times of under 8ms) than for my laptop to feed them into Pub/Sub.

Is there any problem with my implementation? Is this the way I should be doing this?

Also... am I required to wait for all the requests to finish in my `@FinishBundle` method (i.e. by getting the futures returned by the executor and waiting on them)?

Answer (score 4):

You have two interrelated questions here:

1. Are you doing this right / do you need to change anything?
2. Do you need to wait in `@FinishBundle`?

The second answer: yes. But actually you need to flush more thoroughly, as will become clear.

Once your `@FinishBundle` method succeeds, a Beam runner will assume the bundle has completed successfully. But your `@FinishBundle` only sends the requests - it does not ensure they have succeeded. So you could lose data that way if the requests subsequently fail. Your `@FinishBundle` method should actually be blocking and waiting for confirmation of success from the `TheApi`. Incidentally, all of the above should be idempotent, since after finishing the bundle, an earthquake could strike and cause a retry ;-)

So to answer the first question: should you change anything? Just the above. The practice of batching requests this way can work as long as you are sure the results are committed before the bundle is committed.

You may find that doing so will cause your pipeline to slow down, because `@FinishBundle` happens more frequently than `@Setup`. To batch up requests across bundles you need to use the lower-level features of state and timers. I wrote up a contrived version of your use case at https://beam.apache.org/blog/2017/08/28/timely-processing.html. I would be quite interested in how this works for you.

It may simply be that the extremely low latency you are expecting, in the low millisecond range, is not available when there is a durable shuffle in your pipeline.

Comment: Thanks for the response. So yes, I have my pipeline right now blocking in `@FinishBundle` (I save all the futures returned by `.submit{}` and then just loop through them and block on them `.get()`). So far so good. One thing that I don't understand from the UI is the way my pipeline looks like: https://i.imgur.com/SpSrWQt.png What does the "6 days 3 hours" really mean? I see data making it to the other side normally. I really don't understand Dataflow's definition of "Wall time".

Comment: I will give the approach in your post a try. But I'm not sure how I would do parallelism in that one. The external API I need to hit can only handle batches of 75 elements, but I have a few thousand per bundle, so I want to hit the API with a handful of parallel requests (each containing a batch of elements). The problem is that in your post you are assuming that the result of calling the external service will be fed into the next step (using `.output()`) which does not really fit my case since for me this is the last step in the pipeline.

Comment: So I'm running two versions of this pipeline. One with an implementation like the one in my question, except that I'm actually blocking on `@FinishBundle`. The other one using state and timers as you described in the post. The one with state/timers is typically 10 times slower, which I think it's mainly due to the fact that all requests are done sequentially.